# Rails: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound Couldn't find Photo without an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, rails-activestorage

I have  two models, Services and Photos. Under service model belongs_to :user and has_many :photos and has_many_attached :images.

Under photo model belongs_to :service

Under the Photos viewer I'm trying to display the images associated with each service.

I get a Couldn't find Image with an ID error when I try to delete an image.

The Viewer looks like this:

```
<% if @service.images.attached? %>
<br/><br/>

<div class="row">
  <% @service.images.each do |image| %>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading preview">
          <%= image_tag image %>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <span class="pull-right">
            <%= link_to service_photo_path(@photos, image), remote: true, method: 'delete', data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"} do %>
              <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <% end %>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

The Photo Controller looks like this:

```
class PhotosController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @service = Service.find(params[:service_id])

    if params[:images]
      params[:images].each do |img|
        @service.photos.create(image: img)
    end

    @photos = @service.photos
    redirect_back(fallback_location: request.referer, notice: "Saved...")
  end
end

  def destroy
    @photo = Photo.find(params[:_id])
    service = @photo.service

    @photo.destroy
    @photos = Photo.where(service_id: service_id)

    respond_to :js
  end
end
```

routes:

```
service_photos POST /services/:service_id/photos(.:format)photos#create 
service_photo DELETE /services/:service_id/photos/:id(.:format) photos#destroy
```

Comment: Could you run `rake routes` and show us related routes to these models?

Comment: service_photos POST     /services/:service_id/photos(.:format)photos#create
service_photo DELETE   /services/:service_id/photos/:id(.:format)                                        photos#destroy

Comment: as I expected you should use `params[:id]` not `params[:_id]` refer to my answer below in the answers section and mark it as correct if it did help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
@photo = Photo.find(params[:_id])
```

with:

```
@photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
```

I think you have typo! `id` not `_id`

---

Also, in your view replace:

```
service_photo_path(@photos, image)
```

with:

```
service_photo_path(@service, photo)
```

Comment: Now the error changed to ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Photo with 'id'=10)

Comment: @klasarn, I've updated the answer with additional changes :) please follow it and feedback!

Comment: You need to figure out how to get the `photo` .. you are mixing the usage of `photos` and `images`.

Comment: When I use photo instead of image I get the error "Undefined local variable or method". I know that I'm mixing the usage of photos and images, since I had to switch from paperclip to activestorage...

Comment: The `routes` and `controller` shows that you are dealing with `photo`s. Then you pass an image!! In your view you need to use `@service.photos` instead of `@service.images` you need to decide what are photos and what are images and how you can use them!! you can't pass `image` to `service_photo_path` while it expects `photo`.

Comment: When I just use @service.photos it only returns the service_id and not the id of the image associated with the service. While image returns the id of the picture.

Comment: Again, what is a `photo` and what is an `image`? This confusion is making it ridiculous!